# egrep is returning 0 in bash script but executing manually the command returning correct value | unix bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ftp, grep

I'm executing a bash script that returns me if ftp connection failed or was success using egrep, the issue is that when I'm trying to get a word with egrep is returning 0 but If I execute the command manually is returning 2.

this is my code:

```
#Create the FTP Connection.
for ip_address in ${IP_ADDRESS[@]}; do
  ftp ${ip_address} <<ftp_commands > ${FTP_RESULTS}
  user "${USER_ID}" "${USER_PASSWORD}"
  pwd
  bye
ftp_commands

ftp_result_id=`egrep -c "Login failed|Connection refused|Not connected|Connection timed out" ${FTP_RESULTS}`

if [ ${ftp_result_id} -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "$(date +%m/%d/%y_%H:%M:%S) - ${ip_address} - Not connected" >> ${CONNECTION_RESULTS_FILE}
else
    echo "$(date +%m/%d/%y_%H:%M:%S) - ${ip_address} - Connected" >> ${CONNECTION_RESULTS_FILE}
fi

done
```

the ftp_results_id is returning 0 in the egrep -c command, but I'm executing manually after it ran and create the file "FTP_RESULTS" and is working, it suppose that found 2 matches with "Not connected"

any suggestion?

Comment: Use `grep -Eq` and then use exit code

Comment: @anubhava grep -Eq is not returning anything...

Comment: Like all commands, it returns with a useful exit code. `if grep -Eq "your terms" yourfile; then echo "It had matches"; fi`

Comment: Could the error be written to the stderr? Might `2> ${FTP_RESULTS}` work?

Comment: I had to use a a nested if, that's how worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The `egrep -c` command counts the matches.
Then you use a condition to do something if there are more than 0 matches.

A simpler and better solution is to use the exit code of `egrep`.
`egrep` exits with 0 (= success) if it found a match,
and non-zero otherwise.
You can write the `if` statement like this:

```
if egrep -q "Login failed|Connection refused|Not connected|Connection timed out" "${FTP_RESULTS}"; then
```

This is equivalent to the logic in your posted code.
There's no need for the `ftp_result_id` variable.
And there's no need to save the output of `egrep`.
I added the `-q` flag so that `egrep` doesn't produce any output.
None needed.